# How to click java swing control using AutoIT?

Tags: java, swing, autoit

I'm trying to automate my Java application using *AutoIt* but I'm having difficulties in clicking some button.

I think *AutoIt* know where's the controls are, as you can see highlighted below, the problem is it won't click the control.

[image: Java Application Screenshot]

Here is my source code...

```
    String jacobDllVersionToUse;
    if (System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model").contains("32")) {
        jacobDllVersionToUse = "jacob-1.18-x86.dll";
    } else {
        jacobDllVersionToUse = "jacob-1.18-x64.dll";
    }

    System.out.println(jacobDllVersionToUse);

    File file = new File("autoit", jacobDllVersionToUse);
    System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());

    AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
    String hWnd = "GfcEmulator-Hybrid";
    String exeDir = "C:\\GFC\\resources\\props";
    String exeName = "GFCEmulator_Automation.jar";

    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c cd " + exeDir + " && " + exeName + "");
    x.winActivate(hWnd);
    x.winWaitActive(hWnd);

    x.ControlSetText(hWnd, "", "[CLASS:RichEdit20W; INSTANCE:1]", "____________");
    x.ControlSetText(hWnd, "", "[CLASS:RichEdit20W; INSTANCE:2]", "____________");
    x.ControlSetText(hWnd, "", "[CLASS:RichEdit20W; INSTANCE:3]", "____________");
    x.ControlSetText(hWnd, "", "[CLASS:RichEdit20W; INSTANCE:4]", "____________");

    x.controlClick(hWnd, "", "[CLASS:ComboBox; INSTANCE:1]");
    x.controlSend(hWnd, "", "[CLASS:ComboBox; INSTANCE:1]", "{down}+{enter}");

    x.sleep(1000);
    x.controlClick(hWnd, "", "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]"); // Click Connect Button, I already tried every method I know just to make this work but it all fails.
```

**Other Details:**

OS : Windows 10

Button Info:

[image: Connect Button Information]

Comment: Have you tried a controlfocus() just before the controlclick() ?

Comment: Also I can't remember if the autoit option "MouseClickDownDelay" applies to control click, so you may try increasing it from its default of 10ms.

Comment: @garbb Yes, I already tried to use `controlFocus()` but it's the same.

Comment: I already have an workaround for this. I calculate the window position and button position inside the form and used the `mouseClick()` instead, it takes over my mouse control but its fine.

Comment: So, you are able to control all other controls except that CONNECT button? Try focusing the window again, then the control and then try to send controlclick. Also, another solution is to focus the button and send enter or space with ControlSend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto IT has limitation on detecting controls in Java Swing

I found a work around by following this Guide from AutoIT forum : [Java UDF](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/87956-java-udf/)

This UDF provides automation support for Java applications.

This UDF currently automates standalone applications and browser-based applets, developed in either Swing or the Abstract Window Toolkit (AWT).